# ASP.NET MVC Structure/Logic

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a few questions about where the logic goes in a MVC app.

This is a sample action in a controller and was wondering if this is too much logic, and if so, where else would you put it:

FYI - `Manager` is sort of a service type layer where we transform BO to DTO/ViewModels back and forth to another layer that does our BL

```
Public Function ChangeClaim(model As ChangeClaimViewModel) As ActionResult
        Manager.SetClaimNumber(model.ClaimNumber)

        Dim securityToken = Manager.ClaimSecurityToken

        If (securityToken.ValidClaim) Then
            Session("ClaimNumber") = model.ClaimNumber
            If (Not securityToken.ConflictAccess) Then
                ModelState.AddModelError("ClaimNumber", "You do not have access to this claim.")
            End If
        Else
            ModelState.AddModelError("ClaimNumber", "Invalid claim number.")
        End If

        If (Not ModelState.IsValid) Then
            Return View(Manager.GetViewModel())
        End If

        If (model.URL.Contains("ChangeClaim") OrElse model.URL.Contains("EnterClaim")) Then
            model.URL = Url.Action("Index", "Home")
        End If

        Return Redirect(model.URL)

    End Function
```

Also, I would assume that hanging `bool` of a ViewModel to use to do logic like so in a view is OK?

```
@if (Model.HasExposureAccess)
    {
        <li><a href="#tab-pane-2">@Model.Labels.Reimbursements</a></li>
    }
```

Any other suggestions for improvement?

Oh and sorry for the mix of VB & C#, the shop I work in does everything except the views in VB and I had to fight to get to do the views in C#!!??

**EDIT #1**

So as for the `If (securityToken.ValidClaim) Then` let me just try my best to run you through the process and see if you have any suggestions.

When a user tries to change the claim number, it comes in on the model, it is passed off to the `Manager.SetClaim` method (the managers are a sort of service layer we created to be able to use our existing BO framework which, don't laugh, is a heavily modified version of CSLA.NET V1, they are very tightly coupled objects as far as the BL and DAL all live inside the objects. Not my choice at all, but what do you do :)) which validates that it is a valid claim and the user has access to it. I am trying my hardest to keep the layers separated as best possible:

1) MVC App
2) Application Managers
3) Existing BOF

Did I make any sense?

**Edit #2**

So I have put the logic from the controller action into an action filter like so:

```
Public Class ValidateClaimAttribute
Inherits ActionFilterAttribute

Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(filterContext As System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext)
    MyBase.OnActionExecuting(filterContext)

    Dim model As ChangeClaimViewModel = CType(filterContext.ActionParameters("model"), ChangeClaimViewModel)
    Dim manager As IInjuredWorkerManager = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(Of IInjuredWorkerManager)()
    Dim securityToken = manager.ClaimSecurityToken

    manager.SetClaimNumber(model.ClaimNumber)

    If (securityToken.ValidClaim) Then
        filterContext.HttpContext.Session("ClaimNumber") = model.ClaimNumber
        If (Not securityToken.ConflictAccess) Then
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("ClaimNumber", "You do not have access to this claim.")
        End If
    Else
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("ClaimNumber", "Invalid claim number.")
    End If

End Sub
End Class

<ValidateClaim()>
    Public Function ChangeClaim(model As ChangeClaimViewModel) As ActionResult
        If (Not ModelState.IsValid) Then
            Return View(Manager.GetViewModel())
        End If

        If (model.URL.Contains("ChangeClaim") OrElse model.URL.Contains("EnterClaim")) Then
            model.URL = Url.Action("Index", "Home")
        End If

        Return Redirect(model.URL)

    End Function
```

Does this look like more of the correct way of doing this?

**Edit #3**
So, I have further optimized to this:

```
<ValidateClaim()>
    Public Function ChangeClaim(model As ChangeClaimViewModel) As ActionResult
        If (Not ModelState.IsValid) Then
            Return View(Manager.GetViewModel())
        End If

        Return New MyRedirect(model.URL)

    End Function
    Public Class ValidateClaimAttribute
Inherits ActionFilterAttribute

Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(filterContext As System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext)
    MyBase.OnActionExecuting(filterContext)

    Dim model As ChangeClaimViewModel = CType(filterContext.ActionParameters("model"), ChangeClaimViewModel)
    Dim manager As IInjuredWorkerManager = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(Of IInjuredWorkerManager)()
    Dim securityToken = manager.ClaimSecurityToken

    manager.SetClaimNumber(model.ClaimNumber)

    If (securityToken.ValidClaim) Then
        filterContext.HttpContext.Session("ClaimNumber") = model.ClaimNumber
        If (Not securityToken.ConflictAccess) Then
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("ClaimNumber", "You do not have access to this claim.")
        End If
    Else
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("ClaimNumber", "Invalid claim number.")
    End If

End Sub

End Class

Public Class MyRedirect
Inherits ActionResult

Private _url As String

Public Sub New(url As String)
    _url = url
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub ExecuteResult(context As System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext)
    Dim urlHelper As New UrlHelper(context.RequestContext)

    If (_url.Contains("ChangeClaim") OrElse _url.Contains("EnterClaim")) Then
        _url = urlHelper.Action("Index", "Home")
    End If

    context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(_url)
End Sub
End Class
```

Full Controller Code:

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Security.Principal
Imports Telerik.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Globalization

Namespace Controllers
<HandleException(View:="Error")>
<OutputCache(Duration:=0)>
Public MustInherit Class InjuredWorkerController
    Inherits SAIF.Web.Mvc.Framework.Controllers.ContextController



    Public Property Manager As IInjuredWorkerManager

    Public Sub New(manager As IInjuredWorkerManager)
        _Manager = manager
        _Manager.ValidationDictonary = New ModelStateWrapper(ModelState)


    End Sub

    <ValidateClaim()>
    Public Function ChangeClaim(model As ChangeClaimViewModel) As ActionResult
        If (Not ModelState.IsValid) Then
            Return View(Manager.GetViewModel())
        End If

        Return New MyRedirect(model.URL)

    End Function

    Public Function SetCulture(culture As String, returnUrl As String) As ActionResult
        Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie("culture") With {
                             .Value = culture,
                             .Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
                         })

        Return Redirect(returnUrl)

    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub ExecuteCore()
        Dim cultureName = "en-US"
        Dim cultureCookie = Request.Cookies("culture")

        If (cultureCookie IsNot Nothing) Then
            cultureName = Request.Cookies("culture").Value
        End If

        Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName)
        Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName)

        MyBase.ExecuteCore()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(filterContext As System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext)
        MyBase.OnActionExecuting(filterContext)

        Dim controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values("controller").ToString
        Dim action = filterContext.RouteData.Values("action").ToString

        If (action.ToLower = "enterclaim" OrElse action.ToLower = "changeclaim") Then
            Return
        Else
            Dim claimNumber As String = String.Empty
            Dim workerID As Decimal

            If (Session("ClaimNumber") IsNot Nothing) Then
                claimNumber = Session("ClaimNumber").ToString
            End If

            If (Session("WorkerID") IsNot Nothing) Then
                workerID = CDec(Session("WorkerID"))
            End If

            If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(claimNumber)) Then
                If (workerID = 0) Then
                    If (Manager.IsExternalUser) Then
                        workerID = Manager.GetWorkerIdByDomainUser
                        claimNumber = Manager.GetMostRecentClaimNumber(workerID)
                    Else
                        filterContext.Result = New RedirectResult("/MyClaim/Home/EnterClaim")
                    End If
                End If
            End If

            Manager.SetClaimNumber(claimNumber)

        End If

    End Sub

    Public Function SendMessage(<Bind(prefix:="SendMessage")> model As IWSendMessageViewModel) As ActionResult
        Manager.SendAdjusterEmail(model.AdjusterEmail, model.PersonEmail, "IW Contact Message", model.Message, model.SendCopyToSender)
        Return Json(New With {.message = "Success"}, "application/json")
    End Function

End Class

End Namespace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's definitely way too much for a controller action. Things like `If (Not securityToken.ConflictAccess)` should go into a custom `Authorize` attribute that your controller action should be decorated with. Things like `ModelState.AddModelError("ClaimNumber", "Invalid claim number.")` go into a custom validation  attribute, or if you are using [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) (which I very strongly recommend you to) in a FV validator for your model.

Things like this:

```
If (model.URL.Contains("ChangeClaim") OrElse model.URL.Contains("EnterClaim")) Then
    model.URL = Url.Action("Index", "Home")
End If
```

could go into a custom action result that you will return.

As far as your conditional logic in the view is concerned, it is fine. You could use your view model properties to show/hide certain UI elements. Obviously proper authorization (via custom Authorize attributes) should be done in the corresponding controller actions, because the fact that you have hidden a link from the user doesn't mean that a malicious user cannot forge a request and still be able to invoke your controller action.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am still struggling to understand how I would accomplish these tasks. If you look Edit #1, I try to explain a little better the process, maybe that would help you help me :) Thanks again!

Comment: So it is OK to access data (think manager :) ) from within Action Filters and Fluent Validators?

Comment: Yes, it is OK. It allows to unclutter your controller actions.

Comment: Will you look at Edit #2 above and see what you think?

Comment: OK, things are starting to look much better. The last step is to write a custom action result to avoid the url replacing part in your controller but simply do `Return New MyRedirect(model.URL);` and it will be the custom MyRedirect action result that will take care of replacing and stuff.

Comment: OK, look at Edit #3. What do you think? Also, what about the rest of the controller code, like `ExecuteCore` and `ActionExecuting` could those be optimized?

Comment: OK, look at Edit #3. What do you think? Also, what about the rest of the controller code, like ExecuteCore and ActionExecuting could those be optimized? What about using the DependencyResolver to locate the service inside the filter, is that gonna be an issue when it comes time to unit test these controllers?